# Represent hour number using roman numeral in circle

Tags: c++, opengl

Is it possible to represent the hour number using roman numeral around circle like im using circle dot as hour number for my pendulum clock. Below is my code for my dot representing hour number around circle:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.6, 0.0);
    glRotatef(circleMarks2 += 30, 0, 0, 1);
    float cm1;
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);

    glColor3ub(75, 44, 13);
    for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
    {
        cm1 = (i * 3.142 / 180);
        glVertex2f(0 + 0.007 * cos(cm1), 0.12 + 0.007 * sin(cm1));
    }

    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
  }
```

i can't find a way to do the roman numeral around circle automatically using looping, right now im doing it manually using:

```
  glRasterPos3f(-0.025, 0.68, 0);
  char msg1[] = "XII";
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(msg1); i++)
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, msg1[i]);
```

is there any steps to use roman numeral around circle using loop just like the one i use but with circle dot?

Comment: What's the problem? Each hour division falls along a vector. Just extend further out along that vector to determine a "center" position of the bounding box for your text, then offset by half the width and height of that box to get the top-left corner (or whatever baseline `glRasterPos3f` assumes for text) and draw your string. Create an array containing the roman numeral representation for each hour, and do all this in a loop.

Comment: alright, i can visualize the solution now, thank you soo much!